# Discord.py Import commands from another py

Tags: python, discord.py

im trying to Import commands from another PY file. But it always Says command not exists...

This is my code in the file named test.py

```
from discord import Embed
from random import choice
from colorama import *
from os import path
from plyer import notification

intents = discord.Intents().all()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ">", intents=intents)

@commands.command()
async def haha(ctx):
    await ctx.send("hi")

import customcmd


client.run("censored")
```

The code in customcmd.py is

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands, tasks

@commands.command()
async def hi(ctx):
    await ctx.send(hi)#
```

Comment: Getting this error

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lequi\Desktop\test.py", line 22, in <module>
    from .customcmd import *
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
from .customcmd import *
```